# Why can't I get full bandwidth from WinUsb_ReadIsochPipeAsap?

Tags: windows, usb, winusb

I have multiple `WinUsb_ReadIsochPipeAsap` in flight at a time and always queue the next one as soon as `WinUsb_GetOverlappedResult` succeeds for the first.  According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn265565(v=vs.85).aspx):

> WinUsb_ReadIsochPipeAsap allows the USB driver stack to choose the starting frame number for the transfer. If one or more transfers are already pending on the endpoint, **the transfer will be scheduled for the frame number immediately following the last frame number of the last currently pending transfer**.

(emphasis added)

When I measure the data rate on the host (rate of read completion), I am only seeing a polling rate of 6ms (every 6th frame), even though the descriptor `bInterval` is `1`, and 6ms isn't even a possible polling interval for isochronous endpoints.  The documentation makes me think I should see a transfer on every frame, because I always have multiple pending transfers.

If I look at the bus with a USB analyzer, I don't see any `IN-NAK` from the device, so I suspect Windows is not even making the request.

Why don't I see the full 1000Hz transfer rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to `WinUsb_ReadIsochPipeAsap`:

```
BOOL __stdcall WinUsb_ReadIsochPipeAsap(
  _In_     PWINUSB_ISOCH_BUFFER_HANDLE BufferHandle,
  _In_     ULONG                       Offset,
  _In_     ULONG                       Length,
  _In_     BOOL                        ContinueStream,
  _In_     PULONG                      NumberOfPackets,
           PUSBD_ISO_PACKET_DESCRIPTOR IsoPacketDescriptors,
  _In_opt_ LPOVERLAPPED                Overlapped
);
```

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn265565(v=vs.85).aspx), the meaning of `ContinueStream` is:

> `ContinueStream [in]`
>
> Indicates that the transfer should **only** be submitted **if** it can be scheduled in the first frame after the last pending transfer.

(emphasis added)

And this is true.  For example, if your very first call to `WinUsb_ReadIsochPipeAsap` passes `TRUE`, you will get `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` because there is nothing to continue.  If you allow more than 1 frame of time (1ms in full speed) and pass `TRUE`, you will get `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` because the "first frame after the last pending transfer" is no longer available.

**However**, despite the very similar language about "first frame after the last pending transfer" being the default behavior, **the only way Windows will actually schedule the transfers to be in sequential frames is if `ContinueStream` is set to `TRUE`**.  It doesn't matter how fast you call `WinUsb_ReadIsochPipeAsap` or how many overlapped calls you make.

The solution is to always try to `ContinueStream`, but fall back to not continuing in case there is a hitch (else you will fail forever after the first failed `ContinueStream`):

```
ContinueStream = FALSE;

while (...)
{
    if ( !WinUsb_ReadIsochPipeAsap( ..., ContinueStream, ... ) )
    {
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();

        if ( lastError == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER && ContinueStream)
        {
            ContinueStream = FALSE;
            continue;
        }
    }
    ContinueStream = TRUE;
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite your loop to use `WinUsb_ReadIsochPipe` (the non ASAP version), but that just requires you to manage the sequential frame numbers yourself.